Irreducible but not absolutely irreducible representations
Let $\mathbb F_q$ be a field of $q$ elements where $q$ is an odd prime power. Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $\rho:G \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb F_q)$ be an irreducible representation over $F_q$ which is not absolutely irreducible. Let $\operatorname{Frob}_q$ be the Frobenius map sending $x\in \overline{F}_q$ to $x^q\in \overline{F}_q$.

Why is $\rho$ of the form $V\oplus \operatorname{Frob}_q(V)$, where $V$ is a 1-dimensional representation of $G$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q$?

Here I think that $V$ corresponds to a group homomorphism $G\to \mathbb{F}_{q^2}^{*}$ because the characteristic polynomials of matrices in $ \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q) $ is of degree 2. By assumption, $\rho$ is reducible over $\overline{F}_{q^2}$, so it is expected to yield a splitting as a direct sum $V\oplus W$. But what I don't understand is why the complement of $V$ is $W=\operatorname{Frob}_q(V)$.
Thanks for your help.

Is $V$ really supposed to be a representation over $\mathbb{F}q$? Assuming you mean to write $\overline{\mathbb{F}}q$, if this representation is actually defined over $\mathbb{F}{q^2}$, then consider that $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}{q^2}/\mathbb{F}_{q})$ has order $2$ and the nontrivial automorphism is Frobenius.

Thank you, indeed I meant that $V$ is over $\overline{\mathbb F}q $. I fixed it. But since the minimal polynomial is of degree $2$, the eignvalues should live in a degree $2$ extension of $\mathbb{F}{q}$, which is $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ (up to isomorphism). Is it not necessarily the case?

Abbreviate $K=\Bbb{F}_{q}$, $L=\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$, $k=\overline{K}$ to save a few keystrokes.
Let $U$ be the space $k^2$ with $G$ acting on it via $\rho$ (composed by the inclusion $GL_2(K)\hookrightarrow GL_2(k)$, if you prefer). Because $\rho$ is not absolutely irreducible, $U$ is not irreducible, and hence has a $G$-stable 1-dimensional (over $k$) subspace $V$. Let $\vec{x}\in k^2$ be a vector spanning $V$.
Without loss of generality we can assume that the first non-zero component of $\vec{x}$ is equal to $1$. Anyway, $\vec{x}$ is a common eigenvector of all the matrices $\rho(g), g\in G$. Let $\chi(g)\in k$ be the eigenvalue. The eigenvalues are, as you pointed out, necessarily from the quadratic extension field $L$.
The other component of $\vec{x}$ cannot be an element of $K$, for otherwise $\vec{x}$ would span a 1-dimensional subspace of $K^2$, stable under the action of $G$. And this would violate the irreducibility assumption. Let's extend the definition of $F=Frob_q$ to vectors and matrices (componentwise). It follows that $\vec{x}$ and $F(\vec{x})$ as linearly independent (over $k$). But $F(\vec{x})$ is also a common eigenvector of all the matrices $\rho(g), g\in G$. This can be seen by applying $F$ to the equation
$$
\rho(g)\vec{x}=\chi(g)\vec{x},
$$
when we arrive at (observe that $F(\rho(g))=\rho(g)$ because $\rho(g)=\in GL_2(K)$):
$$
\rho(g)(F(\vec{x}))=F(\chi(g))F(\vec{x}).
$$
So the space $W$ spanned by $F(\vec{x})$ is another $k$-subspace of $U$ stable under $G$. As $\vec{x}$ and $F(\vec{x})$ are linearly independent, they must span all of $U$, and therefore $U=V\oplus W$.

As you see, nothing deep was going on. This kind of arguments are relatively quite common in representation theory of finite groups, when stuyding the effect of extending the field of scalars (see e.g. Curtis & Reiner). This may be why the details were glossed over in your book.

It is likely that I gave too detailed a description. In that case I apologize for making you read an unnecessarily long post.

On the contrary, thanks a lot for the amazingly detailed answer, it made it much clearer to me. I had one more question, could you please explain why $\vec{x}$ and $F(\vec{x})$ are linearly independent over $k$? It is obvious? And many thanks also for the nice reference!

I think I see why $\vec{x}$ and $F(\vec{x})$ are linearly independent over $k$. It is a consequence of the fact that the second component of $\vec{x}$ does not lie in $K$. I apologize for asking this obvious question.

Yeah, the reason I normalized $\vec{x}$ to have its first component $=1$ was to make it easier to see why $\vec{x}$ and $F(\vec{x})$ are linearly independent: the resulting $2\times2$ matrix has $1$s on the first row, but the entries on the second row differ $\implies \det\neq0$ :-)

Amazing :-), many thanks!
